# React + flux make changes on state when action dispatched

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm trying to update view's state when flux action is actually dispatched. I'm having a list of TODO's and want to give user functionality to remove selected TODO's (simple check checkbox and fire with a delete button). I'm having a little annoying issue when deleting the item from list. Here some code to have it more clear:

```
deleteSelectedTodos() {
  actionTodoRemove(this.state.todosSelected);
  this.setState({
    todosSelected: [],
    toggleAll: false
  });
}
```

So this basically works, but it uncheck the todo's before they actually dissapears from list. But I really have to clear the todosSelected list cleared after the deletion is dispatched.

```
[*] todo 1
[ ] todo 2
[*] todo 3
```

and then:

```
[ ] todo 1 // it will dissapear after dispach, and is unchecked
[ ] todo 2
[ ] todo 3 // it will dissapear after dispach, and is unchecked
```

Is there any option to run some callback which will make a changes on state? I was thinking about setting some code in componentWillMount/DidMount but it doesn't feels right since it's called on every component change and I want to filter the selected list only when single prop is changed.

Comment: Have you tried creating an e.g. `unselectTodos` action that you call (instead of `setState`) after `actionTodoRemove`? Actions ought to run in the order they're dispatched, so that should give you the desired result.

Comment: I don't want to make selected todos member of global state, I'd rather keep it in local component state.